# How to create a curved nav bar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create a nav bar like this.But i cant create exactly like this.please help me.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4 text-right">
            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 round text-center">
            <img src="images/sss-logo.png" class="sss-logo">
        </div>
        <div class="col-4 text-left">

        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

I'm doing like this:

[image]

I need to create like this:

[image]

Comment: The images are in the wrong way I guess

Comment: yes its in wrong order sorry for that..

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle too?

Comment: I would create the entire navbar background as an SVG, in a case like this. It's probably the only way you can get the correct shadow.

Comment: I would use SVG for this

Comment: Here is Fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/38m9wxa6/6/

Comment: Thanks i will try to create SVG..@tocqueville And @enxaneta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea using `drop-shadow` filter and gradient:

```css
.header {
  height:50px;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(darkblue,darkblue) right calc(100% - 33px)/calc(50% - 43px) 4px,
    linear-gradient(darkblue,darkblue) left calc(100% - 33px)/calc(50% - 43px) 4px,
    radial-gradient(circle at 50% -20px, transparent 64%,darkblue 66%,darkblue calc(66% + 2px),transparent calc(66% + 3px)) bottom center/100px 35px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  filter:drop-shadow(0 3px 4px #000);
}


body {
 margin:0;
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">

</div>
```